# ManyToMany does not save to db Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a ManytoMany field and the results of the `CheckboxSelectMultiple` don't get saved in the db and i don't understand why. It must be really simple but...

Here's the code:

> models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):

    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name +" "+self.first_name

class Event(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
        person = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

> forms.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.get('user',None)
        #self.user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        #self.helper.form_action = reverse_lazy('simpleuser')
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success'))     

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['person']
        widgets ={
        'person': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        }
```

> views.py

```
def uploadevent(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form =EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            event = form.save(commit=False)
            event.owner = request.user
            event.save()
    else:
        form = EventForm()

    return render...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the response on this stackoverflow question: [Saving Many To Many data via a modelform in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612991/saving-many-to-many-data-via-a-modelform-in-django)

Quoting the OP:

> When using commit=False, you have to call save_m2m()
>
> m2m relationships require the parent object to be saved first, which
>   you are not doing by using commit=False

Just add this line below `event.save()`

```
    if form.is_valid():
        event = form.save(commit=False)
        event.owner = request.user
        event.save()
        form.save_m2m()
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Answer (score 0):

To save manytomany you should call `save_m2m()` when using `commit=False` (check details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)):

```
if form.is_valid():
        event = form.save(commit=False)
        event.owner = request.user
        event.save()
        form.save_m2m()
```